# Moon's orbit and its phases

Tags: the-moon, orbit, observation, astronomy

After learning what apogee and perigee are, I'm curious to know if/when these stages align with particular phases of the Moon? I'm obviously assuming that the orbit has a repeating pattern, but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: When the periapsis coincides with Full Moon, you're facing the [Supermoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermoon) phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. Most lunar cycles won't align with its orbital distance to Earth (perigee at its closest or apogee at its farthest). There is however an *orbital pattern*, or a resonance if you will, that combines both periodically and it's called a [full moon cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_moon_cycle) which is roughly 14 lunations long period when the Moon will be full at roughly its perigee. When the Moon is both the closest to Earth (perigee) and also in [opposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposition_%28planets%29) (on the other side of the Earth than the Sun) at exactly the same time, a [supermoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermoon) eclipse happens. This is another such cycle and it is called [saros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saros_%28astronomy%29). It occurs every 18 years and a bit, or 223 [synodic months](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_month#Synodic_month) (time between one full moon and another).